# Accepting New Events in PubNub While Others Are Still Processing

Tags: python, events, event-handling, pubnub

Newer beginner here!

I am attempting to automate the playing of a grindy game using multiple computers with Python.

This is how it works

1. Computers 1, 2, ...., n stare at one area waiting for a specific colour to appear.
2. When a colour appears on one of the computers, it sends a message "Computer n" to Computer 0 (The main computer) through PubNub.
3. Computer 0 takes about 2 minutes to join the game of Computer n, perform an activity and leave.

**The problem is that the colour can appear at any time - even simultaneously on multiple computers.**

I only have one account on the main computer, so I'm fine with it taking 2 minutes each. Although it means that new events will be getting published while the previous is still processing. Once the backlog reaches more than 10 minutes I would like to ignore all new events as the main computer won't have time to reach them.

There is no way for me to currently tell how long the backlog is as I just process it in the Subscribe function. As soon as it finishes processing one event it immediately moves onto the next without being able to see how many more there are.

Is there a way I can add the events to a list while it's being processed at the same time? This would allow me to check how many events I have to do and ignore future ones if there are too many.

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to what your requirements or issues are but with respect to waiting 2 minutes, that is not a thing. PN will deliver the results in realtime (<100ms in most cases). So something is wrong if you are waiting 2 minutes. Can you provide some insights by providing some sample code?

Comment: "Is there a way I can add the events to a list while it's being processed at the same time? This would allow me to check how many events I have to do and ignore future ones if there are too many." Specifically for this, you could just send the messages even if it won't be processing them. I think this is a "best practices" discussion best had over a call. Is this a real-world project or just a fun one-off project you are doing?

Comment: Hey Craig! This is just a side project of mine. The 2 minutes of wait time involves my program manually moving the mouse and walking the character in-game. To do this I use Time.sleep() after pressing down w to make it walk to the destination.

Comment: You mention me being able to just "send the messages even if it won't be processing them". That's my current idea, I'm wondering if there's another way around forcing the subscribe function to finish its 2 minutes before accepting the next message. Apologies for unclear requirements, really appreciate your willingness to help!

Comment: just unsure why would want to force the subscribe to NOT respond in real time (which no, you can't do really). I would say look at using Signals (see docs) as they are cheaper than publish (if you end up going over your Free monthly limit of 1MM tx) but the payload must be < 64 bytes. But just let the messages flow. That's why you are using PubNub. Otherwise you are getting into a short poll design which you don't need PN to do that.

Comment: "if there's another way around forcing the subscribe function to finish its 2 minutes before accepting the next message" - I'm still puzzled by this statement. The Subscribe will finish when a message is published to the channel it is subscribed to or after 280s of no messages. Either way, the SDK will just submit a new subscribe to continue to receive more messages. You can always stop the subscribe by calling `unsubscribe` but you would have to call `subscribe` again to start receive messages again but do not do this. Just subscribe and receive messages as they are published.